# Database problem in visual studio (c# and SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am writing a Windows Forms app in which I have to simulate keeping count of who is missing in class. I have made a database inside Visual Studio which works well. I also found a tutorial on youtube on how to do it, so I did it. In one part of the video he puts an "@(Name of the variable in the table)" instead of a value in query. For him it works, for me it doesn't and i don't know why. Please help.

```
private void napuniUcenici()
{
    string query = "SELECT a.Ime FROM Ucenici a " +
                   "INNER JOIN RazrediUcenici b ON a.Id = b.UcenikId " +
                   "WHERE b.RazredId = @RazredId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazredId", lstUcenici.SelectedValue);

        DataTable uceniciTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(uceniciTable);

        lstUcenici.DisplayMember = "Ime";
        lstUcenici.ValueMember = "Id";
        lstUcenici.DataSource = uceniciTable;
    }
}
```

This happens when I call this function in my code. And it returns this massage:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>
> 'The parameterized query 
>   '(@RazredId nvarchar(4000))SELECT a.Ime FROM Ucenici a INNER JOIN'
>   expects the parameter '@RazredId', which was not supplied.'

Also, `RazredId` isn't a `navchar(4000)`, it is a regular integer. The guy in the video didn't have this problem.

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PCBTiXL884

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKIpZ.png)

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1HPE.png)

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRU0K.png)

Comment: Have you checked `lstUcenici.SelectedValue` value? I'm sure it can't be null and maybe it is

Comment: There is no value in the listbox. Should there be a value in there?

Comment: You're trying to apply a filter to the query, it should be a value.

Comment: It says `nvarchar(4000)` because you used AddWithValue. AddWithValue is not a good thing to use - you should find a better tutorial. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I looked at the link you sent and the examples they provided said that it has to equal something and just don't know what. I am not very experienced with database integration.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Dapper for data access. It is a free Nuget package. Tim Corey made an excellent introductory tutorial at Youtube. (search for IAmTimCorey and Dapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, so... I am dumb xD
What i did wrong is that the second parameter in this line was wrong(the lstRazredi was previously lstUcenici which is the wrong table)

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazredId", lstRazredi.SelectedValue);
```

So i changed that and now i works perfectly.
Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1):

try to pass an explicit value instead:
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RazredId", 1);
and see whats's happen. It is correct to retain the @ in the param name, unlike as previous repolies.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to add the parameter before you pass the command to the adapter?

Comment: I think this is better a comment

Comment: I agree, but I cannot make comments yet.    and you're not really helping :)